# Fundamental regions in convex programming

Tags: convex-geometry, convex-optimization, convex-analysis, linear-programming, semidefinite-programming

In linear programming, the fundamental regions are polyhedra, since those are the intersection of half-spaces defined by linear inequalities. In semidefinite programming, the fundamental regions are spectrahedra$^\color{magenta}{\dagger}$:

> A spectrahedron is the intersection of the cone of positive semidefinite matrices with an affine-linear space.

What are the fundamental regions in convex programming in general?

---

<sub>$\color{magenta}{\dagger}$ Bernd Sturmfels, [GAeL Lecture I on Convex Algebraic Geometry — Spectrahedra](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ebernd/coimbra1.pdf), Coimbra, June 2010.</sub>

Comment: Would "feasible" be better than "fundamental"?